# Object in Angular Component not defined in handler when its event calls callback

Tags: javascript, angular, createjs

I am playing with createjs and angular. I am trying to update() my stage when my image loads. I believe I am running into an Angular problem here though. When the load event on the Bitmap object completes and its callback runs, the stage object is not defined. As a matter of fact, the Bitmap object that created the event is reported as not defined (see sample code below).

Events raised by onClick and the like from within the HTML do not suffer this same problem and the toString() method returns some info about the object.

I believe that I am not understanding a DI principle or something here.  I have played with this quite a bit and cannot find an answer or come up with a solution. Your help is appreciated.

```
Angular version information:
Angular CLI: 1.6.6
Node: 8.9.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.6.6
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.29
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.52
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.6
@schematics/angular: 0.1.17
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.10.0
```

createjs installed via: npm install createjs-module --save

---

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import * as createjs from 'createjs-module';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  bmp: createjs.Bitmap;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.bmp = new createjs.Bitmap('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/SIPI_Jelly_Beans_4.1.07.tiff/lossy-page1-220px-SIPI_Jelly_Beans_4.1.07.tiff.jpg');
    this.bmp.image.onload = this.bmpOnLoad;
    this.bmp.name = 'BmpName';
  }

  bmpOnLoad(): void {
    console.log(this.bmp.toString());
  }
}
```

Console has an error that says `Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined`

Comment: Adding a stackblitz::: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gitter-wbydgb

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @ericmartinezr of angular/angular in gitter.

Eric gave me the following code snippets which work around the fact that referring to properties of "this" in the callback fails:

```
this.bmp.image.onload = () => this.bmpOnLoad();
```

or

```
this.bmp.image.onload = this.bmpOnLoad.bind(this);
```

What I would appreciate is an explanation as to why this works.  Isn't there one singleton component that is being referenced? Why does the callback have access to objects that aren't initialized when they are available by other means?

Comment: That is called 'fat arrow' in Typescript and it will capture the meaning of `this` and the context, so when you call to `this` inside of a fat arrow you will have the same context that you have outside of that function.

Comment: I understand, but why (in the original code) does it seem that the "this" inside the callback is not the same "this" that was used to set the callback in the first place. Almost like the function being called does not belong to the original object. I thought that the DI defaulted to a singleton which means one copy. Or is there some DI magic that controls the addressing so that the callback is not aware of its parent object?